# How to cluster group of vectors?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have around 1000 vector each with 9000 numeric value. I need some way to find similarities between them or cluster them. What is the approach/algorithm for doing that ? 
I thought about k-means, but does it work with data like that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In such very high dimensions (9000) you are more than likely to suffer from the curse of dimensionality, I would suggest running a dimensionality reduction algorithm (e.g PCA or T-SNE) prior to using a clustering algorithm in such very high dimensions.

You can read more about dimensionality reduction techniques [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/dimensionality-reduction-techniques-python/)

You can also learn more about the curse of dimensionality and why it is difficult to find meaningful clusters in high dimensions [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/curse-of-dimensionality-2092410f3d27).

Comment: You cannot use PCA with fewer observations than variables, and tSNE is also affected by the curse of dimensionality, because it relies on the Euclidean distances in the input space.